# Does a device like this exist?

Tags: audio

I'm looking for a portable device that has jacks (3.5mm would be best but anything works) for a microphone input and speaker output, and then connects via Bluetooth to my phone or computer and appears to it as a Bluetooth headset. Audio played through the "headset" would be sent out out the speaker output on the device and signal sent to the input of the device would be "received" as if coming from the microphone on the "headset."

**Does a device like this exist? I'm not sure what it'd be called or how to search for something like this.**

This pertains to live media production, if there's a better SE site please advise.

Comment: Supporting mic input will be tricky but everything else shouldn't be to hard https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0728GP9XH/?tag=stackoverflow17-20

Comment: But see, that's the trick of it- I'm looking for a single device that does both! I've only been able to find one or the other...

Comment: I'm looking for a device that has the ability to send stereo sound input and receive stereo sound input at the same time over Bluetooth... the device linked would provide very poor quality for a microphone, and I'm looking for something handsfree. Ideally a performer will have a microphone hanging on their ears (hands-free) and a monitor in their ear, so they can both speak into the mic and hear whatever audio is sent over Bluetooth.

Comment: I am saying I do not believe the typical standard for microphones will allow for stereo transmission over bluetooth.  As a possible workaround you could feasibly have 2 devices.  The 1 posted above and this one https://www.walmart.com/ip/Mini-3-5mm-Bluetooth-Audio-Transmitter-A2DP-Stereo-Dongle-Adapter-for-TV-iPod-Mp3-Mp4-PC/791933627?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=973&adid=22222222227065093679&wmlspartner=wmtlabs&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=169610021704&wl4=pla-274776371973&wl5=9009544&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=113148614&wl11=online&wl12=791933627&wl13=&veh=sem Would require some special cables

Comment: Interesting... Considering video can be streamed over Bluetooth I am a bit skeptical that its a protocol limitation... Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Your Bluetooth video argument isn't convincing.  In my experience Bluetooth video is is laggy and has artifacts.  The protocols evolve by use case.  I'm just looking at the history of how this evolved. If the isn't greatly distinguishing then it won't exist.  Lots of lavaliere mics are mono. It doesn't make sense when you have a directional one mic to have stereo input the vast majority of the time.

Answer (score 2):

I may have this wrong, but the following might be close to what you want.  [PLUB: Don't plug in, PLUB in!](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/864001667/plub-dont-plug-in-plub-in)

This is a tiny Bluetooth receiver that connects to wired headphones or earphones.

Description from the KS website: "Make wired headphones wireless! PLUB is the most affordable, compact and simplest-to-use Bluetooth receiver."

The KS campaign is finished and these devices are available from a number of sources.

If this isn't exactly what you want, it might be worth contacting the creators of this project to see if they can create what you are looking for.  That's the main reason for including the link to the KS campaign page.

Comment: Technically assuming the microphone works it will still be mono.

Comment: This looks like a potentially good option! I appreciate the suggestion to get in touch with the team, that's a wise idea. I'll have to reach out to them for sure!

Comment: So, as a follow up: It seems that this device would in theory do what I wanted to do, but I've found no evidence that the Kickstarter delivered the devices at all. @Dwayne Reid what sources do you have that this device is available at all? I called the company's California office and the number was reassigned to someone else, their Facebook page even belonged to a different group, so it seems the company is no longer doing work.

Comment: I did receive my pledge rewards (2 sets) and they do work as promised.  I'll see if I can track down contact information.

Comment: Thanks Dwayne. I've awarded you the bounty. If you can get me some accurate contact information, that'd be brilliant. You can get in touch with my with my email, which you can find on my website linked in my SE profile.

Comment: I have asked the project creator to get in touch with me.  I'll connect with you if he does.